# Update statement followed by select MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am storing cache information from the cache server if application version is matching else I need to set cache details as NULL.

Currently I am doing it like this

```
UPDATE 
  cache_table 
SET
  _data = NULL 
WHERE _id = id AND _app_version != "current_version"
```

Followed by select query

```
SELECT 
      _data 
    FROM
      cache_table 
    WHERE _id = id AND _app_version == "current_version"
```

Is there a way I can do required update and select in one query without firing two query ?

Note: I don't want to use MySQL procedure. No specific reason but don't want to store application logic in DB so I can easily change database application.

Comment: I think you're missing a `,` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Or an `AND`. That probably actually works.

Comment: @tadman AND 
It should match both the condition. Application version and cache id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `UPDATE` and `SELECT` are two distinct operations. The only way to combine them is with a stored procedure as you identify.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe in MySQL there is a built-in way to do this. However, just FYI this can be done in SQL Server using OUTPUT clause:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx